# Tags not parsing - showing on front-end like {slideshow}{/slideshow},{path},{slide_show_links},{file} etc

Tags: templates, ee1, tags

I am totally new to expression engine.  I inherited a project that is built with expression engine because the last developer disappeared.  The site was working fine for the last two years so i didn't have to really touch it.

A couple of weeks ago, the site started showing problems.  My slideshow galleries and some images aren't showing up anymore.  I can even see tags like {slideshow}{/slideshow},{path},{slide_show_links},{file} etc.. showing right in the webpage.  These tags are supposed to be replaced php code to do things like printing the html mark up of galleries, or printing urls etc...

An example of this problem can be seen at http://hop.ca .

Comment: Could you share some more info if you updated field's name or field type or upgraded EE.

Comment: Did the symptoms begin on their own? Or had you made an edit, changed a setting, removed a fieldtype, or anything else in the control panel before this occurred? As Bhashkar indicates, if you can provide whatever information you can on what might have happened immediately before the symptoms occurred, we'd be in a better position to provide a bit of guidance.  Based on the {slideshow}{/slideshow} appearing within the page, I might guess it has to do with a Matrix field - but that's not necessarily where the problem will have started - it may simply be a clue as to where to look.

Comment: Is only the homepage affected?

Comment: Looks like you have a Nivo slider on the menu covers page that is also not displaying correctly. It may be something different or it may be a symptom of the same root cause.

Comment: Hi everyone, these problems started happening on their own.  I haven't even touched the site in a whoel year.  Then the client just called me saying it's broken.  We called the host provider to see if they upgraded the servers, and their response was, "We don't know if we upgraded anything.  Let me ask around."  And we never heard from them since.

Comment: So these once worked and now they don't? Can you update your answer to include more info: template code, custom weblog fields, etc. The more you can show, the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it an EE1 site? If so, go to Extensions, then Fieldframe's settings and check the path.

Comment: After our shared hosting reverted back to PHP 5.2.8, and we applied Christy Collins solution, everything worked again.

Comment: oh, and our EE 1.6.8 is not compatible with PHP 5.3.2.  The systems admin broke our site by upgrading php without telling us